# How can I resolve a promised mysql query in express.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to use the npm package promise-mysql and return json data (or a string doesn't matter) but I'm having issues following the promise chain with await/async.

With the current code i'm receiving Promise { undefined } in the console.log I have right before the response to the user. The response just sends nothing to the user and closes it. Can anyone point in the right direction of how to debug this?

#### index.js

```js
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(  Promise.resolve(await getLogs())  ) 
  res.send(await getLogs());
});
```

#### mysql.js

```js
const mysql = require("promise-mysql");

let pool;

async function startDatabasePool() {
    pool = await mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "xxx",
    user: "xxx",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "xxx"
  });
}

async function getDatabasePool() {
  if (!pool) await startDatabasePool();
  return pool;
}

module.exports = {
  getDatabasePool,
  startDatabasePool
};
```

#### users.js

```js
const { getDatabasePool } = require("./mysql");

async function getLogs() {
  let pool = await getDatabasePool();

  pool.query("SELECT * from logs order by logdate desc", function(
    error,
    results,
    fields
  ) {
    if (error) throw error;
    return JSON.stringify(results);
  });
}
module.exports = {
  getLogs
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.js**

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await getLogs();
  res.send(result);
});
```

**mysql.js**

```
const mysql = require("promise-mysql");

let pool;

module.exports.startDatabasePool = async () => {
    pool = await mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "xxx",
    user: "xxx",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "xxx"
  });
}

module.exports.getDatabasePool = async () => {
  if (!pool) await startDatabasePool();
  return pool;
}

// convert function as promise

module.exports.executeQuery = async(params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(params, function (error, result, fields) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**users.js**

```
const { executeQuery } = require("./mysql");

module.exports.getLogs = async () => {
  return await executeQuery("SELECT * from logs order by logdate desc");
}
```

Comment: please [edit this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60555434/edit) with explanation

Comment: Though not the solution I ended up going with, this is a workaround if you're not using the modern convenience variable.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd try it like:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  let logs = await getLogs()
  console.log(logs) 
  res.send(logs);
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: When I do that I get ```undefined``` I have a feeling the users.js file is incorrect. I'm not entirely sure how to return the pool.query promise. Do I make the callback async as well? Or just return the entire pool.query, returning everything up the chain?